# How do I make sure my column descends by year instead of the day of the month?

Tags: r, date, posixct

Given I have the column x

```
head(daily_negative_PRscore$x)
"2018-01-02 10:29:00 CET" "2017-01-03 18:28:00 CET" "2017-01-03 19:29:00 CET" "2018-01-03 00:00:00 CET" "2017-01-04 10:47:00 CET" "2017-01-04 11:05:00 CET"
```

And the way I would it to descend ideally is in the following manner:

```
2017-01-03 18:28:00  2017-01-03 19:29:00 2017-01-04 00:00:00 ...
```

Comment: `daily_negative_PRscore <- daily_negative_PRscore[order(as.POSIXct(daily_negative_PRscore$x)),]`

Comment: Thank you very much !! That worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use `arrange`:

```
library(tidyverse)

daily_negative_PRscore %>% 
  arrange(desc(as.POSIXct(x)))
```

Or another base R option with `as.Date`:

```
daily_negative_PRscore[rev(order(as.Date(daily_negative_PRscore$x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))),]
```

**Output**

```
                        x
1 2018-01-03 00:00:00 CET
2 2018-01-02 10:29:00 CET
3 2017-01-04 11:05:00 CET
4 2017-01-04 10:47:00 CET
5 2017-01-03 19:29:00 CET
6 2017-01-03 18:28:00 CET
```

**Data**

```
daily_negative_PRscore <- structure(list(x = c("2018-01-02 10:29:00 CET", "2017-01-03 18:28:00 CET", 
                                               "2017-01-03 19:29:00 CET", "2018-01-03 00:00:00 CET", "2017-01-04 10:47:00 CET", 
                                               "2017-01-04 11:05:00 CET")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                -6L))
```

Comment: This one is ascending by year. OP wants it to descend by year. Include the `desc`fucntion

Comment: @Onyambu I ended up not using it at first, as the answer in the comments does not use `rev` and the OP said it worked. So, guess it's a little unclear. But I went ahead and updated assuming that they do need it descending. Thanks.